# Strip imports & exports from react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't use a dependency/package manager or build system but I want to use a component like this: https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-clusterize/blob/master/src/Clusterize.jsx

Specifically...

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// CLASS CODE
export default Clusterize;
```

Notice it uses "import" and "export" despite being code that is specifically for a browser. I understand this is very common and many projects use build systems to deal with this but I cannot.

How do I strip the import/exports to get the class into the global scope. Is there a library or cli that can do this?

Comment: You won't be able to use import/export without a build tool. What is the end goal you are trying to achieve? Do you plan on using any 3rd party packages or just things you build within the app?

Comment: We have a large project where the codebase is mostly browser-first react components. We manually load components and other libraries on demand to improve performance and seo. We want to use a 3rd party library or component and need to fork every time to remove the nodejs code and that gives us rapidly aging technical debt. We tried webpack but the code-chunking plugin is not smart enough to know what the user has already downloaded. It also took code out of the global namespace and since we're using react-rails to render in the backend, that made it an unacceptable limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can include React, ReactDOM and Babel directly in the browser and use them without webpack or gulp. However for production environment you will need to include minimised versions of these script files.

To render anything you have to pass rows prop to ClusterizeComponent like:

```
<ClusterizeComponent rows={ data } />
```

This code should give you a good start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='app-root'></div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/clusterize.js/0.17.6/clusterize.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
            (() => {
                class ClusterizeComponent extends React.Component {
                  static propTypes = {
                      rows: React.PropTypes.array,
                      scrollTop: React.PropTypes.number
                  };
                  static defaultProps = {
                      rows: [],
                      scrollTop: 0
                  };

                  clusterize = null;
                  scrollElem = null;
                  contentElem = null;

                  componentDidMount() {
                      const scrollElem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.scrollElem);
                      const contentElem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.contentElem);
                      const rows = this.props.rows.map(row => {
                          if (typeof row === 'string') {
                              return row;
                          }
                          return React.isValidElement(row) ? row : null;
                      });

                      this.clusterize = new Clusterize({
                          rows,
                          scrollElem,
                          contentElem,
                          show_no_data_row: false
                      });
                  }
                  componentWillUnmount() {
                      if (this.clusterize) {
                          this.clusterize.destroy(true);
                          this.clusterize = null;
                      }
                  }
                  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
                      return false;
                  }
                  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                      if (nextProps.rows.length === 0) {
                          this.clusterize.clear();
                          return;
                      }
                      if (nextProps.rows !== this.props.rows) {
                          const rows = nextProps.rows.map(row => {
                              if (typeof row === 'string') {
                                  return row;
                              }
                              return React.isValidElement(row) ? row : null;
                          });
                          this.clusterize && this.clusterize.update(rows);
                      }
                      if (nextProps.scrollTop !== this.props.scrollTop) {
                          this.scrollElem.scrollTop = nextProps.scrollTop;
                      }
                  }
                  render() {
                      const { className, style } = this.props;

                      return (
                          <div
                              ref={node => {
                                  this.scrollElem = node;
                              }}
                              className={className}
                              style={{
                                  height: '100%',
                                  overflow: 'auto',
                                  ...style
                              }}
                          >
                              <div
                                  ref={node => {
                                      this.contentElem = node;
                                  }}
                              />
                          </div>
                      );
                  }
                }

                ReactDOM.render(
                  <ClusterizeComponent />,
                  document.getElementById('app-root')
                );
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: With this solution, import and export still throw errors when including the dependency from npm. It's important to keep versioning and not have to put forks into every third party component.